# Assigning curve fitting polynomial value to a vector

Tags: matlab, vector

I am trying to get a vector of different torque values with respect to speed of an electric motor. To do that I used some torque values at certain speeds and tried to fit a curve to them.

```
tpdata=[0 10 20 30 40 50 60 65 70 75 80 85 90 93.3 95.8 98 99 100];
pdata=[3.3 3.05 2.81 2.79 2.80 2.88 3.02 3.12 3.20 3.28 3.13 2.75 2.10 1.5 1 0.5 0.25 0];
```

I modified it according to my need

```
u=2880/690

ydata=pdata*3.65*u
tsdata=tpdata*30/u
```

I used the curve fitting tool to get the constants.

```
p1 = -2.4592e-20
  p2 = 1.51e-16
  p3 = -2.7946e-13
  p4 = 2.3662e-10
  p5 = -1.0391e-07
  p6 = 2.3887e-05
  p7 = -0.0024883
  p8 = 0.035497
  p9 = 50.272
```

I want to assign the solution of the fitted polynomial (from 1 rpm to 720 rpm) to a vector that I named as y (torque values)

I can get the solution plot but I cannot see them or assign them as a vector.

```
for i=1:720
  y = p1*i^8 + p2*i^7 + p3*i^6 + p4*i^5 + p5*i^4 + p6*i^3 + p7*i^2 + p8*i + p9;
  plot(i,y,'d');
  hold on 
  grid on
  end
```

When I add y=zeros(1,720) and change y to y(1,i) the script fails.

What is the reason of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saving the solution each time in y that is being overwritten in the next loop. You should probably do like this:

```
for i=1:720
      y(i) = p1*i^8 + p2*i^7 + p3*i^6 + p4*i^5 + p5*i^4 + p6*i^3 + p7*i^2 + p8*i + p9;     
end

plot(y,'d');
hold on 
grid on
```

Now you get a vector y(1x720). You dont need to do y=zeros(1,720)...